# Modify a parameter value while solving a partial derivative

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

I'm currently trying to do a sensitivity analysis on a variable `R0` (as defined below). This sensitivity analysis aims to determine what impact has the variation of one of `R0` parameter on this variable. I'm currently struggling to perform the variation of the said parameter in a transformation that implies a `partial derivative` of `R0`.

Here is how is defined my `R0`:

```
R0 = (Umax/u2) * (i2 + (e*ist*b1*u1)/c1);
parameters = {
Umax -> 10000000, 
u1 -> 0.33, 
u2 -> 0.33, 
c1 -> 10, 
b1 -> 6000, 
i2 -> 0.0000001, 
e -> 0.000000001, 
ist -> 0.005
};
```

Then, I want to do a sensitivity analysis on the `u1` parameter. It should be done by this transformation:

```
((D[R0, u1]) * (u1 / R0))  /. parameters;
```

which give me, for a `u1` equals to `0.33`, a score of `0.1089` if I'm not mistaken.

The main problem here is that in the way I chose to resolve my transformation, I can't touch the `u1` parameter anymore. What I want to do is a variation between `0.01` and `1` for this parameter. My first (and naive) idea was to do as following:

```
ParametricPlot[{((D[R0, u1]) * (u1 / R0))  /. parameters, u1}, {u1, 0.01, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "u1"]
```

But, for obvious reasons, it does not work at all.

Should I create a somewhat `list` or `table` of scores for my sensitivity analysis ? Although I'm strongly considering this solution, I'm still stuck on how to vary a parameter in this kind of transformation. I've searched the Mathematica forum but couldn't find a solution that fit my problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `R0[u1_] = ...` and then do `R0'[u1] u1/R0[u1] /. parameters`

Comment: I'm really sorry for the lateness in my answer. Thanks a lot for your comment! This clear up my understanding on this kind of manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The problem was that the list of rules contained the parameter `u1`. Let us exclude it:

```
Clear[R];
R = (Umax/u2)*(i2 + (e*ist*b1*u1)/c1);
parameters = {Umax -> 10000000, u2 -> 0.33, c1 -> 10, b1 -> 6000, 
   i2 -> 0.0000001, e -> 0.000000001, ist -> 0.005};
```

and let us define the function of your wish:

```
g[u1_] := (D[R, u1])*(u1/R) /. parameters // Cancel
g[u1]

(*  (1. u1)/(33.3333 + 1. u1)   *)
```

Now we can plot it:

```
Plot[Evaluate[g[x]], {x, 0.01, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.02}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! This is perfect.